# OpenFaaS serve model using Tensorflow serving

Tags: docker, tensorflow, kubernetes, tensorflow-serving, openfaas

I'd like to serve Tensorfow Model by using OpenFaaS. Basically, I'd like to invoke the "serve" function in such a way that `tensorflow serving` is going to expose my model.

OpenFaaS is running correctly on Kubernetes and I am able to invoke functions via `curl` or from the `UI`.

I used [the incubator-flask](https://github.com/openfaas-incubator/python-flask-template) as example, but I keep receiving `502 Bad Gateway` all the time.

The OpenFaaS project looks like the following

```
serve/
  - Dockerfile
stack.yaml
```

The inner `Dockerfile` is the following

```
FROM tensorflow/serving

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install curl -yy

RUN echo "Pulling watchdog binary from Github." \
    && curl -sSLf https://github.com/openfaas-incubator/of-watchdog/releases/download/0.4.6/of-watchdog > /usr/bin/fwatchdog \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/fwatchdog

WORKDIR /root/

# remove unecessery logs from S3
ENV TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
ENV S3_ENDPOINT=${S3_ENDPOINT} 

ENV fprocess="tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 \
    --model_name=${MODEL_NAME} \
    --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}"

# Set to true to see request in function logs
ENV write_debug="true"
ENV cgi_headers="true"
ENV mode="http"
ENV upstream_url="http://127.0.0.1:8501"

# gRPC tensorflow serving
# EXPOSE 8500

# REST tensorflow serving
# EXPOSE 8501

RUN touch /tmp/.lock
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s CMD [ -e /tmp/.lock ] || exit 1

CMD [ "fwatchdog" ]
```

the `stack.yaml` file looks like the following

```
provider:
  name: faas
  gateway: https://gateway-url:8080

functions:
  serve:
    lang: dockerfile
    handler: ./serve
    image: repo/serve-model:latest
    imagePullPolicy: always
```

I build the image with `faas-cli build -f stack.yaml` and then I push it to my docker registry with `faas-cli push -f stack.yaml`.

When I execute `faas-cli deploy -f stack.yaml -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...` I get `Accepted 202` and it appears correctly among my functions. Now, I want to invoke the `tensorflow serving` on the model I specified in my `ENV`.

The way I try to make it work is to use `curl` in this way

```sh
curl -d '{"inputs": ["1.0", "2.0", "5.0"]}' -X POST https://gateway-url:8080/function/deploy-model/v1/models/mnist:predict
```

but I always obtain `502 Bad Gateway`.

Does anybody have experience with OpenFaaS and Tensorflow Serving? Thanks in advance

**P.S.**

If I run `tensorflow serving` without `of-watchdog` (basically without the openfaas stuff), the model is served correctly.

Comment: Have you checked this ?. https://github.com/alexellis/tensorflow-serving-openfaas

Comment: Yes! Actually, the author created it after I contacted him :) very helpful indeed

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating the link mentioned by @viveksyngh.

**tensorflow-serving-openfaas:**

Example of packaging TensorFlow Serving with OpenFaaS to be deployed and managed through OpenFaaS with auto-scaling, scale-from-zero and a sane configuration for Kubernetes.

This example was adapted from: https://www.tensorflow.org/serving

Pre-reqs:

OpenFaaS

OpenFaaS CLI

Docker

**Instructions:**

Clone the repo

```
$ mkdir -p ~/dev/

$ cd ~/dev/

$ git clone https://github.com/alexellis/tensorflow-serving-openfaas
```

Clone the sample model and copy it to the function's build context

```
$ cd ~/dev/tensorflow-serving-openfaas

$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving

$ cp -r serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu ./ts-serve/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu
```

**Edit the Docker Hub username**

You need to edit the stack.yml file and replace alexellis2 with your Docker Hub account.

**Build the function image**

```
$  faas-cli build
```

You should now have a Docker image in your local library which you can deploy to a cluster with faas-cli up

**Test the function locally**

All OpenFaaS images can be run stand-alone without OpenFaaS installed, let's do a quick test, but replace alexellis2 with your own name.

```
$ docker run -p 8081:8080 -ti alexellis2/ts-serve:latest
```

**Now in another terminal:**

```
$ curl -d '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}' \
   -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8081/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict

{
    "predictions": [2.5, 3.0, 4.5
    ]
}

From here you can run faas-cli up and then invoke your function from the OpenFaaS UI, CLI or REST API.

$ export OPENFAAS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080

$ curl -d '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}' $OPENFAAS_URL/function/ts-serve/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict

{
    "predictions": [2.5, 3.0, 4.5
    ]
}
```